# PHP to protect user changing other users posted

Tags: php, mysql

Considering the following table, when a users log in to the product page, how do I avoid user changing other users products via HTML code since there is no `userId` under product table.

```
Table user
- userId
- name

Store
- storeId
- userId

product
- productId
- storeId
- price
```

Comment: What do you mean by html code?

Comment: how can you tell his own products from others if there is no userId under product table?

Comment: @Col.Shrapnel because there is a storeId under product table

Comment: @mmmshuddup i meant the hidden input behind a browser.

Comment: you have to store user id into session, not HTML code

Answer (score 2):

You can't. Add an `ownerId` field to the `product` table, or add a `userProduct` table containing `userId` and `productId`.

And I don't think users can alter products in your database using html code.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to restrict it on a per-user basis, then it's not possible unless you change your schema structure as there's no direct link between users and products. If you want to do it on a per-store basis, i.e. any user for a particular store can edit any product in that store then a query like the following should get your started

```
SELECT
   [product info]
FROM
   product p
   INNER JOIN
       store s ON p.storeId=s.storeId
   INNER JOIN
       user u ON s.userId=u.userId
WHERE
   p.productId = [productId] AND
   u.userId = [userId]
```

Given a productId and a userId this will enable you to check whether that user is related the store for that product.

Comment: Yes, i guess this is what i want. 
so if i use this way to restrict it. Is it ok?

or this is a bad design?

Comment: Well there are many ways to do access control. I gave this query as an example of how you might restrict access products by store/user. Whether your architecture is good or not is not really something suited to SO. Have a go based on my example and if you get any specific problems post another question.

Answer (score 0):

Do you want sql query ?
If yes 
you can say

`$query = "SELECT * FROM products WHERE storeid IN (SELECT storeid FROM store WHERE userid = ".$logged_user." ) "; 
                           //$logged_user holds the id of the user logged`

Answer (score 0):

You need to define a forth table with following properties

Table purchase
- userId
- productId

And keep information from user purchased items in it.

The original product table should not be used to save changes made by user.